# How do I remove a character from a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a string written in XML which approximates to:
    60-894-74987

I need a line in powershell that will remove the '-' in the string to leave me with '6089474987'

I've been trying to utilize the -replace function, but it either errors or breaks powershell.

the basic code is:

```
$serialnumber= $pcinfo[4] #([4]= <value>60-984-74987</value>) 
$serialnumber= $serialnumber replace '-',"
```

I dont get an error with this, powershell gives me >>

Comment: Please post the code you've tried along with the errors you received.

Comment: I don't see `-replace` in your code. We will need more of your code if we are to assist you. (And edit your question to include the code rather than posting it as a comment.)

Comment: Try using `$serialnumber.Replace("-","")`. That should solve your task.

Comment: @Alex_P that did it! thank you so much for all your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$serialnumber= $serialnumber -replace '-',"`

to

`$serialnumber= $serialnumber -replace '-'`

If you're just deleting characters and not replacing them, you don't need explicit empty quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write as C# fashion below.

```
$serialnumber = $serialnumber.replace("-","")
```